# Show server processes in debian 7

Tags: debian

someone who can take me out, please... I have a server were 7 and want to see exactly which process runs at a certain time, for example::
Every day at 3:00 am.

Comment: -1, as have no idea what you are saying, especially the beginning part. Is the question, “I want to know what process runs every day at 0300hrs. How do I find out? I am using debian 7”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like and put this in `crontab` to run at whatever time you want it to.

```
ps -ef >/tmp/log_$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S)
```